# How to input data into a mysql database from a form when the database already contains a column with data?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a user registration MySql database that I want users to enter data into using a form. This table has a column that I've prepopulated with unique codes. The idea is that each user gets a unique code when they register.

First, is there a better way to handle this than the setup I have?
 Second, if there isn't a better way, how do I update just one row of data for each form submission?

Here's what I'm currently doing:

Register Form

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate();">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" /></p>
<p>Address: <input type="text" name="address" /></p>
<p>City: <input type="text" name="city" /></p>
<p>State: <input type="text" name="state" /></p>
<p>Zip Code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" /></p>
<p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" /></p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Confirm.php

```
<form action="register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate();">
<p>First Name:  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" size="36"     value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>"> </p> 
<p>Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" size="36" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?>"> </p>
<p>Address:  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="36" value="<?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>"> </p>
<p>City:  <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="36" value="<?php echo $_POST['city']; ?>"> </p>
<p>State:  <input type="text" name="state" id="state" size="36" value="<?php echo $_POST['state']; ?>"> </p>
<p>Zip Code:  <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" size="36" value="<?php echo $_POST['zipcode']; ?>"> </p>
<p>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="36" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>"> </p>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="36" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>"> </p>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_values" value="true"> 
<input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm Information">
<input type="button" name="return" value="Change Information"    onClick="javascript: window.history.back(-1)";>
</form>
```

Register.php

```
<?php ob_start();
$url = 'registercomplete.php';
require("register_dbinfo.php");
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();}
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']);
$zipcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['zipcode']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$sql="INSERT INTO users (id, firstname, lastname, address, city, state, zipcode, phone, email)VALUES ('','$firstname', '$lastname', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$phone', '$email')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
mysqli_close($con);
while (ob_get_status()) 
{ob_end_clean();}
header( "Location: $url" );
?>
```

Database columns:

id|promo|tickets|firstname|lastname|address|city|state|zipcode|phone|email

Comment: I think you may have overcomplicated this. If you did this correctly the table would automatically assign a unique ID for each entry in the table.

Comment: You may be right. Perhaps there's a way to "seed" the unique ID so that the code that mysql generates will be usable for our purposes as a promo code?

Comment: You can generate a random, fixed-length string and then check to make sure it doesn't exist before assigning to a user. This might be a circular process until you get one which is unique and can therefore be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question.

If `id` is INT, make the attribute **UNIQUE** with **A_I** (Auto Increment).

If you need a unique string for `promo`, you may want to use an **hashing function** (like SHA-256) in order to avoid string collisions.

In addition to your question I suggest you to not concatenate escaped string since this technique will not prevent SQL injection. You should use [prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on prepared statements and stored procedures. I'll look into that immediately.  id is INT and UNIQUE, but not great for use as a promo code. promo will ideally be 4 alpha characters and 3 numeric characters, so it's easy to remember for the user.

Comment: Also, the promo codes need to be entered into a separate piece of software, so pregenerating them is ideal.

Comment: In these case you only have three choices: (1) design your own hash function, but it is very difficult, (2) do some trick with string concatenation between `microtime()`, some character of some string belonging to the user, but it is not collisionproof for such short codes or (3) generate a random string of 4 alpha and 3 numbers and check if it has already been used (very simple).